# Copy As PDF in MMA 10

Tags: pdf-format, copy-as

Wondering if this is a known issue.. I usually export graphics and Grids using the Copy As PDF menu item. The results looked quite good in MMA 9 on Yosemite. However in MMA 10 on Yosemite, the PDF doesn’t match what I see on screen. Specifically the Font kerning and Fonts look way off… Copy to BitMap function seems to work fine...

Here’s some sample code

```
fstyle12 = Sequence[{FontFamily -> "Myriad Pro", FontTracking -> "Plain", 
FontSize -> 12, LineIndent -> 0}];

fstyle12SemiCondensed = Sequence[{FontFamily -> "Myriad Pro", 
FontTracking -> "SemiCondensed", FontSize -> 12, LineIndent -> 0}];

fstyle12Extended = Sequence[{FontFamily -> "Myriad Pro", FontTracking -> "Extended", 
FontSize -> 12, LineIndent -> 0}];

testText = "Handgloves, Jackdaws, Foxes & Quartz \[Mu]\[Alpha]\[Beta]\[Gamma]\[Delta]";


Grid[
  {
  {Item[Text[testText, BaseStyle -> Evaluate@fstyle12Extended], Alignment -> Left]}
  ,{Item[Text[testText, BaseStyle -> Evaluate@fstyle12], Alignment -> Left]}
  ,{Item[Text[testText, BaseStyle -> Evaluate@fstyle12SemiCondensed], Alignment -> Left]}
  }
, Frame -> False]
```

Produces the following results in MMA10 and when copied to PDF….

[image: Output in MMA10 and in Preview]

Comment: I have been using Copy as PDF on Mavericks and didn't notice any problems.  Can you give more information to make the problem reproducible?

Comment: Will post something this evening… Am on Yosemite DP4… but MMA9 works just fine…

Comment: I can confirm the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t898udi3qznzy84/Screenshot%202014-08-08%2010.59.33.png  (You left an extra backslash in front of delta.)  Can you report it to support at wolfram.com?

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I thought it was me… Looks like this is happening with certain fonts and not all. Specifically, OTF fonts which have multiple weights…

Comment: I confirm the problem, and mention that it has wrought havoc in my workflow, which involved frequent copying of PDFs from mathematica to word processing applications. Back to version 9?

Comment: I filed a bug with Wolfram. And they responded saying they cannot duplicate this bug. I would suggest others to file this bug as well.